# How to keep the Log-In Form from reappearing

Tags: php, html

I'm using the PHPmotion script: http://demo.phpmotiontemplates.com/default/
and I've succeeded in getting the Log-In Form (on the home page) to disappear, once it successfully performs it's function, (which is what I'm trying to accomplish), but as soon as the Log-In function succeeds, and the "sub-menu" on the home page appears,
the Log-In Form reappears again (on the homepage).

So, I'm assuming the sub-menu has something to do with the Log-In Form reappearing.

Which looks like this:

```
<form action="../login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="middletext"
onsubmit="javascript:this.style.display='none';">
<p>
<input type="text" size="20" name="user_name_login" id="user_name_login" value="ENTER     USERNAME" style="color:#D9D9D9" style="vertical-align:middle"; onfocus="if     (this.value=='ENTER USERNAME') {this.value=''; this.style.color='#696969';}" >
<input type="text" size="20" name="password_login" id="password_login" value="ENTER     PASSWORD" style="color:#D9D9D9" style="vertical-align:middle"; onfocus="if     (this.value=='ENTER PASSWORD') {this.value=''; this.style.color='#696969';}" >
<input type="hidden" name="cookie_time" value="10080" />
<img src="../themes/default/images/arrow-red.png" alt="" /><input type="submit"   style="outline:grey" font-size="5px" value="[var.lang_login_now]" class="button-form2" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="remember_me" value="remember_me" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<!--Begin Sub-Navigation. This only appears when a user is logged in.-->
<div class="container1">
<div class="menu1">
<div class="sub-nav"><a href="../index.php"></a>&nbsp;<img     src="../themes/default/images/arrow-red.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" alt="" /><a    href="../members/[var.user_name]"> my account</a><img src="../themes/default/images/arrow-    red.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" alt="" />
<a href="../credits.php">[var.lang_my_credits]: [var.member_credits]</font></a><img     src="../themes/default/images/arrow-red.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle"><a     href="../logout.php">[var.login_out]</a>
<!--[onload;block=div;when [var.loggedin]=1;comm]-->
</div>
```

Any thoughts/solution about this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){ //dont show form } else { //show form }`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show me where/how to integrate that into the Form code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['YOUR-SESSION-NAME'])){

         echo '<form action="../login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="middletext"
    onsubmit="javascript:this.style.display=\'none\';">
    <p>
    <input type="text" size="20" name="user_name_login" id="user_name_login" value="ENTER     USERNAME" style="color:#D9D9D9" style="vertical-align:middle"; onfocus="if     (this.value==\'ENTER USERNAME\') {this.value=\'\'; this.style.color=\'#696969\';}" >
    <input type="text" size="20" name="password_login" id="password_login" value="ENTER     PASSWORD" style="color:#D9D9D9" style="vertical-align:middle"; onfocus="if     (this.value==\'ENTER PASSWORD\') {this.value=\'\'; this.style.color=\'#696969\';}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="cookie_time" value="10080" />
    <img src="../themes/default/images/arrow-red.png" alt="" /><input type="submit"   style="outline:grey" font-size="5px" value="[var.lang_login_now]" class="button-form2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="yes" />
    <input type="hidden" name="remember_me" value="remember_me" />
    </p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!--Begin Sub-Navigation. This only appears when a user is logged in.-->
    <div class="container1">
    <div class="menu1">
    <div class="sub-nav"><a href="../index.php"></a>&nbsp;<img     src="../themes/default/images/arrow-red.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" alt="" /><a    href="../members/[var.user_name]"> my account</a><img src="../themes/default/images/arrow-    red.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" alt="" />
    <a href="../credits.php">[var.lang_my_credits]: [var.member_credits]</font></a><img     src="../themes/default/images/arrow-red.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle"><a     href="../logout.php">[var.login_out]</a>
    <!--[onload;block=div;when [var.loggedin]=1;comm]-->
    </div>';

} else {

     echo 'You\'re already logged in!';

}

?>
```